# How to find data when results set is in array?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to find data through id, i have an array like that

```
$result= 

 Array
 (

   [3] => 536371014
   [38] => 1435902884
   [53] => 100000224980743
)
```

user _id is

```
  [3], [38], [53]
```

in my user tabe

```
    user_id    name 
     3          usii
     38         test
     53         test 2
```

i want to find all data through user id, how can i do that with the result set user id which is index, i tried alot but didn't get success, please help me to do that, thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. What do you mean with "find all data"? If its a sql query you use `WHERE user_id=3` and when its in the array you just use `echo $result[3]`

Comment: using this ids `[3], [38], [53]` to find name in table  ?????

Comment: `$result[$user_id]` is not an option ?

Comment: yes using all ids in mysql query.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE user_id=3` or `SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE user_id IN (3, 38, 53)`

Answer (score 6):

Use foreach like this

```
foreach($result as $val) {

   echo $val[$user_id];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work (brutal pseudo code)

```
in_list = implode(", ", array_keys($result));
$all_users = mysql.query("select * from user_table where user_id in (" . in_list . ");";
```

array_keys should give you an array of just the indexes used (3, 38 and 53)
implode with ", " as glue should give you a string like this "3, 38, 53" suitable for a mysql [IN condition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in).

Answer (score 2):

```
$user_ids = implode(",",array_keys($result));
$query = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE user_id IN (".$user_ids.")";
```